# Shopify API returns all products instead of single product

Tags: php, api, curl, shopify

I am calling the Shopify API with the following:

nameofmystore.myshopify.com/admin/products.json/#410319192096?fields=id,images,title

It is returning a list of all products and all fields on my store instead of just the product with the ID 410319192096 and the fields I require.

According to the documentation I am calling it correctly, does anyone know if I'm making an incorrect call?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong placement of `.json` in your url, if you only want to select single product, not all list ([info here](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product#show)).

Correct url for single product should be:
`nameofmystore.myshopify.com/admin/products/410319192096.json?fields=id,images,title`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much for your help.